# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.auth.transport.rest'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api

working on a project that lists stores nearby. I'm using Google My Business Information API with Python. No matter what I do, I can't get rid of this error. Is there any solution for this?

My code starts with

```
import google.auth
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.auth.transport.rest import AuthorizedSession
```

And I did these already

```
pip install google
pip install google-auth
pip install google-auth-oauthlib
```

Comment: According to https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/reference/google.auth.transport.html#submodules there is no such module.

Comment: Why did you **expect** that module to be available?  Did you copy that import statement from some example?

Comment: I got confused while I'm trying to send HTML requests so I asked ChatGPT about it. It suggested this unknown module.

Comment: With the current state of AI, if you do not already know how to interface with an API or service, AI generated code will often make your job harder. Always consult the Google documentation first, which usually includes examples to help you get started.

Comment: By the way: AI content is [not allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) here.